# ST_Intersects with the whole world doesn't bring back all results

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I have a table of devices with a column `last_known_coordinates` (geography(Point,4326)).

I want to find devices within a bounding box with a query. Some bounding boxes are working, but others are not - it seems the bigger they get, at some point they stop working. To test this, I tried to search (almost) the whole world:

```
SELECT "device".* 
FROM   devices AS "device" 
WHERE  (ST_Intersects("device"."last_known_coordinates", ST_MakeEnvelope(179, -89, -179, 89)::geography))
```

This brings back **none** of the records, where I would expect all to be returned. Why aren't all records returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole world polygon is not supported by the PostGIS **geography** type as documented in  https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_usage.html#PostGIS_Geography_AdvancedFAQ

> 4.1.2.3.3.
>
> What is the longest arc you can process?
>
> We use great circle arcs as the "interpolation line" between two
> points. That means any two points are actually joined up two ways,
> depending on which direction you travel along the great circle. All
> our code assumes that the points are joined by the *shorter* of the
> two paths along the great circle. As a consequence, shapes that have
> arcs of more than 180 degrees will not be correctly modelled.

Comment: Just adding for OPs reference: this does not apply to the `GEOMETRY` type. But that type has plenty other limitations.

Comment: Thank you. So for arcs of more than 180, I suppose we'll need to break the bounding box in (at least) two.